# AC Power Socket Connector without polarity connected to switching power supply module

Tags: power-supply, electricity

I bought a switching power supply module to convert ac power from wall into dc for my electronic Projects. It looks like this:
[image]
**it looks like that without the case/cover:**
[image]
[image]

I plan to connect the module to male plug IEC320 C8 AC Power Socket Connector rated: 2.5A 250V. It looks like this:
[image]

The C8 AC Power Socket Connector will receive electricity from my wall. As you can see the AC Power Socket Connector do not have polarity. It can be connected either way, but the supply module AC INPUT pins is marked with N and L.

Do i need some reverse electricity protection ?

Do i have to connect the C8 AC Power Socket in a certain polarity with the supply module because of the N and L ? or it will work in any polarity?

Please help me to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the next answer will help you:

[Does AC Power have Polarity?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/137104/does-ac-power-have-polarity)

In your case,  this is an isolated power supply (it seems to me that the transformer is the big yellow part). The diode bridge recrifiers transforms AC to DC, and it does not matter the AC polarity. You can connect the wires either way.

Comment: I will try to see if i can get the datasheet - i was concerned with the ac input marked with N and L and assumed that it could not just connect the wires either way

Comment: I found the datasheet here: http://www.inhaos.com/uploadfile/otherpic/AM01%20AC-DC%20module.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3Djew0mUQG3sTKLB2oYq9vfc3-f2oyYYRJLFEOUxsndxn6G-UoSJrA4es

Comment: Yes, you can connect the wires either way

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

It's AC, you can't do reverse protection.
It looks like any other switch mode power supply, only thing related to mains socket is that there is a blue capacitor between mains side and isolated side for EMI compatibility. Basically it matches standard USB power supply.

Comment: So i can connect the wires either way ? even that they marked ac input  with N and L ?